# Is there a repository for academic slides?

Tags: presentation, repository

Open access repositories like arXiv make it easy to archive one's papers at a stable place where everyone can download them.

However, in my field (computer science), many publications are conference publications, and they are presented by giving a talk (in addition to the paper). The slides of the talk can often be very helpful to understand the paper (or refresh one's memory, when one attended the talk). In addition, keynotes, tutorials, invited talks, course material, etc., are also many other reasons why academic prepare slides about their research.

Academics sometimes put their slides on their professional webpages (or on the websites of conferences, workshops, etc.), but these are not stable and often go offline after some years (e.g., when academics change institutions). That's a pity: one would imagine that there should be a website like arXiv but to deposit slides, keeping information about when the talk was given, which paper the talk refers to, etc.

**Does such a website exist?**

Comment: A lot of people use [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/), but I would argue it is nothing like arXiv.

Comment: @StrongBad: Yes, I know that there are general-purpose slide sharing websites, but as I have tried to point out, I would say that preserving slides of academic talks (and structured metadata about them) is especially important, so I'm looking for something else. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Are you sure you cannot put slides on arXiv?  I think I might have seen it.

Comment: You can put slides on sites like figshare or zenodo, which are specifically for academic materials. It's not clear what characteristics you are looking for in such a repository, though, so I'm not sure that answers your question.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: I've never seen it, but maybe it exists, I'm not sure how I could look for it.

Comment: @ff524: I think the repository should keep track (in a structured way) of the paper the slides are referring to, when the presentation took place, etc., which you probably wouldn't get if the slides were just on Zenodo or figshare.

Comment: (I've bee an arXiv moderator since 2007.) ArXiv papers are expected to be scientific research _papers_. I don't think I've ever seen sometime try to submit a slide deck, but if someone tried, I would be very surprised if the administrators _didn't_ reject it.

Comment: I once asked with Greg Kuperberg (chair of the arXiv math advisory committee) what he thought of the idea of posting talk slides on the arXiv.  He was very clear that he didn't think that would be an appropriate use of the site.

Answer (score 2):

For computer science, the video lectures site is very helpful, [VideoLectures](http://videolectures.net/Top/Computer_Science/)

This site includes a bunch of videos from well-known researchers in the computer science world from the top conferences in this field like KDD, NIPS and many others. Along with the videos of the presentation, you can easily download the slides material of the presentation (although you can't download the video files from this site). 
I recommend you to see this site.

Comment: Too bad that you can't download the videos. Their FAQ says that the policy should change in the near future <http://videolectures.net/faq/> but has said so for the last 4 years at least <https://web.archive.org/web/20120513074420/http://videolectures.net/faq/>. Also, many videos require Adobe Flash even to be played. Further, I didn't see any information in the footer about who is behind this website (for-profit or not?), and their blog is dead <http://blog.videolectures.net/>. This doesn't look great...