# Is there a repository for copyrighted academic video lectures?

Tags: copyright, online-learning, intellectual-property, covid-19, audio-video-recording

As the **Covid-19 pandemic** spread out everybody’s moving to **teach online**. Would it be possible to post online my video lectures, without sacrificing **copyrights**, i.e. posting them with a **warranty** that (at least) any university could not reuse them to teach online courses without my permission?

My question is somewhat similar to this other one [Is there a repository for academic slides?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72635/is-there-a-repository-for-academic-slides). However I don’t care so much about the option to download the video lectures.

Is this feature already available in **YouTube** or **Vimeo** instead?

Comment: I suggest you talk to an IP lawyer. It may well be that putting it online is just a form of publishing with full copyright retained (I am not a lawyer). If you have copyright you can (probably) set the licensing terms to others (such as universities) as you please. But that requires legal language and a willingnes to defend your claims. Most people will respect your rights but some will claim you have none at all. Your university probably has an office that deals with IP issues and has lawyers on staff or on call.

Comment: Copyright law heavily depends on what country you’re in.

Comment: When you upload a video on YouTube, you can mark it as "Public", "Private" or "Unlisted". When it is "Unlisted", it won't be found using a normal YouTube search. You should attach a copyright statement to the videos though; you can record a short sequence that you attach to each video using a basic video editing tool.

Comment: That's a very good option, to rely on YouTube, thanks a lot @Tsundoku !